# How to append user inputted values into different columns of a df?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a `df` based on the user inputs as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','QTY', 'MOA', 'TAX'])

while True:
    add_seg = input('Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: ')
    if (add_seg == 'Y')|(add_seg == 'y'):

        id_value = input('ID ')
        qty_value = input('QTY ')
        moa_value = input('MOA ')
        tax_value = input('TAX ')

        data['ID'].append(int(id_value))
        data['QTY'].append(int(qty_value))
        data['MOA'].append(int(moa_value))
        data['TAX'].append(int(tax_value))

    else:
        break
```

Whenever the user wants to enter a segment, he selects `Y` and starts entering the values. Now, I want to add these values to a `df` too. I tried appending it, but it gives me the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "", line 13, in 
>       data['ID'].append(int(id_value))
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 2775, in append
>       to_concat, ignore_index=ignore_index, verify_integrity=verify_integrity
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py",
>   line 255, in concat
>       sort=sort,
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\kashy\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\concat.py",
>   line 332, in **init**
>       raise TypeError(msg)
>
> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ''; only
>   Series and DataFrame objs are valid

**Example:**

```
Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: y

ID 66

QTY 654

MOA 6565

TAX 6

Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: y

ID 656

QTY 61

MOA 65

TAX 64651
```

and from these values, a `df` must be formed as follows:

```
ID    QTY    MOA    TAX
66    654   6565     6
656    61     65    64651
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can crete dictionary and use [`DataFrame.append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID','QTY', 'MOA', 'TAX'])

while True:
    add_seg = input('Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: ')
    if (add_seg == 'Y')|(add_seg == 'y'):

        id_value = input('ID ')
        qty_value = input('QTY ')
        moa_value = input('MOA ')
        tax_value = input('TAX ')

        d = {'ID':int(id_value),'QTY':int(qty_value),'MOA':int(moa_value),'TAX':int(tax_value)}
        data = data.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    else:
        break

print (data)
```

Another idea is create list of dictionaries with `python append` and last call `DataFrame` constructor:

```
L = []
while True:
    add_seg = input('Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: ')
    if (add_seg == 'Y')|(add_seg == 'y'):

        id_value = input('ID ')
        qty_value = input('QTY ')
        moa_value = input('MOA ')
        tax_value = input('TAX ')

        d = {'ID':int(id_value),'QTY':int(qty_value),'MOA':int(moa_value),'TAX':int(tax_value)}
        L.append(d)

    else:
        break

data = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['ID','QTY', 'MOA', 'TAX'])
print (data)
```

Answer (score 1):

After the inputs use:

```
data.loc[len(data)] = [int(id_value), int(qty_value), int(moa_value), int(tax_value)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, append empty row and then set its columns:

```
while True:
    add_seg = input('Do you want to add a segment (Y/N)?: ')
    if (add_seg == 'Y')|(add_seg == 'y'):
        data = data.append({}, ignore_index=True)
        last_row = data.iloc[-1];
        for c in data.columns:
            last_row[c] = int(input(c))
    else:
        break
```